# Im so stuck with this Set Theory Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A \subset B$ and $B \subseteq C$ then $C \not\subseteq A$.

My proof attempt:

Assume $C \subseteq A$ implies that for all x an element of C, x is also an element of A. Since $A \subset B$, it follows that x is an element of A implies that x is also an element of B. Thus, for all x an element of C, x is also an alement of B, thus $C \subseteq B$. Now, since $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq B$, it implies that B=C.

(I am stuck at the last line, I can't see any contradiction to my assumption $C \subseteq A$)

Any insights will help, I have learned lessons from my previous posts anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful!  $\subsetneq$ is not the same as $\not\subseteq$.

Answer (score 2):

To show $C\not\subseteq A$, it's enough to show that there is an element of $C$ that is not in $A$. There must be such an element, because $B\subseteq C$ and there is some element of $B$ that is not in $A$.